# Cannot get inner HTML from an element

Tags: javascript

[image]

Just wondering why do I get an output of NaN not 100 using this code (the class was changed to time recur by the way, it's not on the screenshot but keep it in mind):

```
z = +(document.getElementsByClassName("time recur").innerHTML)
```

Comment: View the docs on `getElementsByClassName` it doesn't return a single element

Comment: ... Is there a reason you posted an image of HTML rather than just, you know, the HTML? It wouldn't even take that much time to just type that out.

Comment: What's the purpose of "+" at the beginning btw?

Comment: you could use z = +(document.querySelector(".time.recur").innerHTML);

Comment: @neocorp: adding + will covert it to number : alternative for parseInt

Comment: Thank you for the info @BrajendraSwain

Comment: Clarification to some of the below answers: `getElementsByClassName` does _not_ return an array, at least not one with the `Array` prototype. It returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so don’t be surprised if `Array` prototype methods don’t work on your element list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does getElementsByClassName return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByClassName returns an array.

```
z = +(document.getElementsByClassName("time recur")[0].innerHTML)
```

By the way,I can't see the class 'recur' in your element. You might need to ignore it in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Because **getElementsByClassName** returns array.

```
z = +(document.getElementsByClassName("time recur")[0].innerHTML)
```

Comment: My answer was the same

Comment: :) yes, same answers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
z = + parseInt((document.getElementsByClassName("time recur")[0].innerHTML));
```

When you select element by class, you might get more than one matched element, so you have to select first with index 0. And then, you have to convert it to Integer in order to use in math operation. Hope this helps.